# idiom request for "classic is good"

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom for telling "Classic is good.".

The term "Classic is good" by itself tells what I want actually, but I want a more intense saying instead.

Comment: "Classic is best"?

Comment: Please can you give us some context for how you will use the phrase?

Comment: It is just out of curiosity actually. But the real context is my girlfriend bought a new pair of shoes and said that they are too classic and boring. And I wanted to tell that "Classic is best" :). In fact the topic is already off the table, but I still am curios about the saying itself.

Comment: Classic is cool? (better alliteration). You could replace _classic_ with _retro_, which is usually used for old fashion that comes back _into_ fashion (or as an excuse to wear your mom's dress ).

Comment: It's not an idiom, but *[timeless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/timeless?q=timeless)* might be a fitting adjective for what you're trying to convey.

Comment: *Tried and true*?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: In the IT world, ["No one ever got fired for buying IBM"](https://salesforlife.com/blog/no-one-ever-got-fired-for-buying-ibm/) is common, but that's more about "regular stuff that everybody recognizes" than about "classic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

**You can't go wrong with classic**, as a general statement. 
It could be used in sentences like:

- you cant't go wrong with a classic suit, or a classic restaurant. It depends on the context you have in mind.

Comment: Oldie but goodie?

Answer (score 5):

**They don't make them how they used to.**

Comment: That's a good one for the quality of a product.

Answer (score 5):

Your comment is really key to any meaningful answer:

> ...the real context is my girlfriend bought a new pair of shoes and said that they are too classic and boring. And I wanted to tell that "Classic is best"...

So the real question here is one of following the latest trends vs. maintaining a timeless classic *style*.

While not exactly an idiom, the most famous quote related to this would be

> [Fashion passes; style remains](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/03/15/fashion-passes-style-remains/)

which has been bastardized several ways in modern times:

> Fashions come and go, but style goes on forever.

and

> Fashions fade, style is eternal.

Answer (score 4):

"It's a classic for a reason!"

Answer (score 1):

"*The simplest things are also the most extraordinary things, and only the wise can see them*." Paulo Coelho

"*The simplest things are often the truest*"

> [**classic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/classic): simple and harmonious; elegant.
>
> [**simple**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simple): not elaborate or sophisticated; plain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd to for a good old "good old". It it is old and yet still good, that implies that it is timeless, or if you will - a classic.

Answer (score 0):

*Die hard*: meaning it takes a long time to disappear because it is so good.